# ASP.NET MVC Nested List Create and Update

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a Movie class, that in itself contains List of Genres and List of Actors.

```
public class MovieModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public double RunLength { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartingTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndingTime { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string PosterURL { get; set; }
    public List<GenreModel> Genres { get; set; }
    public List<ActorModel> Actors { get; set; }

}
```

So I have 2 many-to-many relationships with appropriate Junction Tables.

I wrote an API that takes a Movie class like in the picture, so  I can update and delete nested objects however I want from postman and program works without problems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaId6.png

In MVC I want to do the same. I want to have a Movie object that I am slowly going to fill First with movie details, then fill List Actors and List of Genres and only after the Movie object is filled send it to service to post or update.

If I update a movie details only from movies controller, how can I send this object to genres controller to add genres and then to actors controller to add actors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post images but the CODE instead

Comment: You have both `asp.net-mvc` (on the full/classic .NET framework) as well as `asp.net-core` on the newer .NET Core framework - which one does this question refer to?? Please be precise and clear.

Comment: Have you try to use database?You can use database to save your data and use [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)to use the  database where data you have saved.